# Word meaning “based on outward appearance”

Tags: american-english

There is a word, on the tip of my tongue...

An adjective I think.  It means something to the effect of “based on outward appearances only, but doesn’t necessarily represent the true nature.”

“__________, Tony was a nice guy.  Sally didn’t know he moonlighted as an axe murderer.”

Comment: Outwardly? Ostensibly? They're not adjectives though.

Comment: Ostensibly is it!  I meant adverb, apparently.

Answer (score 1):

"outwardly" or "On the outside" might fit in here. In the sentence you provide an adverb/adverbial phrase would be more fitting than an adjective.

> Definition of [outwardly](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/outwardly)
>
> 1a : on the outside : EXTERNALLY
>
> 1b : toward the outside
>
> 2 : in outward state, behavior, or appearance
>
> was outwardly friendly

Comment: Maybe my example was flawed.  And yes, I think I meant adverb.  “The Affordable Care Act _______ helps ordinary Americans, but in reality it enriches health insurance company executives”

Comment: Ostensibly!  I googled “outwardly synonyms” and got it!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Superficially**

[Oxford definition](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/superficially): 1 As to the outward appearance only; on the surface.  2 Not thoroughly or deeply.  3 At or on the surface or skin.

> Superficially, Tony was a nice guy. Sally didn’t know he moonlighted as an axe murderer.